# Where to ask questions about Microsoft Word Features

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about how to do something in Microsoft Word. I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site to use. Any tips?

Comment: What kind of questions? Consider [su].

Comment: I have a numbered list.  The first time I use a second level, I want it bulleted.  The second time, I want it to be another numbered list.  Changing it on one second level changes the other second level.  So I guess it's an MS Word feature question.

Comment: @ale: Neither the question nor the answer apply in any way to the placement of a SU question. This isn't about CS or programming, and the answer doesn't list SU at all. Please do not flag questions as a dupe of that master unless it's actually relevant.

Comment: @Nathan: I only suggested that duplicate because it was the duplicate target of two other questions about where to ask about Excel. I've retracted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a question about **how to do something in Microsoft Word**

That's most surely Super User terrain. Most SE sites are about OS's, but Microsoft Word is only supported on Windows and OS X, but the thick of users are on Windows. Just make sure to do your homework before asking (what you tried, what didn't work, how you did, etc.).